# Android Studio 3.5 DataBinding BR fields shown as undefined

Tags: android-databinding, code-editor, android-studio-3.5

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.5, I'm always getting data binding errors in code editor:

[image]

Any autogenerated field inside BR is marked as red and non existent, but still project compiles fine. How can I fix that? Rebuild project, Invalidate Cache and restart, nothing helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are importing wrong `BR` class. I have changed my import from

```
import com.my.packagename.BR;
```

into

```
import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;
```

It is working fine, now. Enjoy coding...

Comment: BR fields no longer generated for @Bindable properties. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136194613

Comment: Yes, that's confirmed bug in 3.5

Comment: Your workaround works .. for now. As I can read, proper fix will be included in 3.6, nobody knows when

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: This solve the problem, but I'm feeling conflict... After generated binding resource (`BR` class) from binding layout (start with `<layout>`). It should be put into application package (Like resource mapping - `R` files). Why It put into 3rd library :D